# how to pass a function to a function with different parameters and execute it c#

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I have a C# app.

I have several different functions with varying return types and varying parameters passed to each function.

I know I can do this:

```
public object RunTheMethod(Func<string, int> myMethodName)
{
    //... do stuff
    int i = myMethodName("My String");
    //... do more stuff
    return true;
}
```

But I may have 2 functions I want to pass through.

The 1st function is as this example shows. It accepts a string and returns an int.  But what if I want to pass an object or no parameters at all etc?

What is the generic option here please.

thanks

@PEOPLE
I have a had a lot of good suggestions here. This is why I love this site. I need to compose myself, get a cup of tea and look thoroughly at these suggestions.

I promise I shall respond.

Thank u all!

Comment: Make `RunTheMethod` itself generic?

Comment: How do you expect `RunTheMethod` to know what parameters to pass to the function? Does run the method pass and `int` in some cases and `string` another?

Comment: @DaveShaw Hi, i am a newbie here. Does the generic method have to have the same signature always?  Can it it dynamic?  The reason I am asking this question is that I have methods that do things (obviously :) ) and I use a complex way of showing a busy indicator in wpf app.  So, I thought I could put the way i invoke this 'busyness' into this generic function and just pass the function to execute the code logic.  I wil have many methods with different signatures.  Just exploring options and hoping to learn from people here :)

Comment: @UnholySheep ah, are you suggesting having a function that passes to a function that then passes to a function?

Comment: Then you just need to use `Action` since you are not providing parameters or using the return value from your generic work function. `() => MyWork(123, "Canada")`

Comment: Where do the parameters come from? It sounds like you can close over them at the call site and just pass an `Action`?

Comment: @Lee actions - let me look at that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this codes help you.

```
   public T Common<T>(Func<T> action)
    {
        //do something log or watch
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public Int32 Run(string query)
    {
        //Set whatever type you want. Or extend generic parameters
        return Common<Int32>(() =>
        {
            return 1;
        });
    }
```

Comment: this looks promising. Thanks for taking mercy on me :) I will test this out now. thanks

Comment: thanks. actually ur answer looks good as compared to the one I accepted.  I need to evaluate this better. But staying away in a contract and I have had a bottle of wine so I do not trust my judgement here. Will take a better look tomorrow..

Comment: you are marked none generic method as a true answer but my answer method type is a generic you can return any value.

Comment: Thank you to @AndrewSimpson :) Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make the function argument take *no* arguments:

```
public bool RunTheMethod(Func<int> f)
{
    //... do stuff
    int i = f();
    //... do more stuff
    return true;
}
```

Then, when calling `RunTheMethod`, you can capture other arguments in lambda expressions, like this:

```
var b1 = RunTheMethod(() => theFunctionThatTakesAString("foo"));
var b2 = RunTheMethod(() => theFunctionThatTakesTwoIntegers(42, 1337));
```

If you want to be able to vary the output type, you can make `RunTheMethod` generic itself, like this:

```
public bool RunTheMethod<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    //... do stuff
    T x = f();
    //... do more stuff
    return true;
}
```

At this point, however, it's a question whether it really makes sense that the input argument is a function. I've noticed that the question is tagged with *functional-programming*; in FP, a more idiomatic design, then, would be to simply let the method take *a value:*

```
public bool RunTheMethod<T>(T x)
{
    //... do stuff
    // no need to call a function to get x; you already have x
    //... do more stuff
    return true;
}
```

Then, calling the method (or function) also becomes easier:

```
var b1 = RunTheMethod(theFunctionThatTakesAString("foo"));
var b2 = RunTheMethod(theFunctionThatTakesTwoIntegers(42, 1337));
```

If you need the value to be a function because you want to be able to control when it gets evaluated, consider using `Lazy<T>` instead.

Comment: I thought it was functional programming as I was using 'Func'.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson No, but it's a start :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to execute arbitrary `Action` instead of `Func`:

```
public object RunTheMethod(Action myMethod)
{
    //... do stuff
    myMethod();
    //... do more stuff
    return true;
}

RunTheMethod(() => Sing("La la la"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call a generic method in this way:

```
public object Execute(MethodInfo mi, object instance = null, object[] parameters = null)
{
    return mi.Invoke(instance, parameters);
}
```

So you're method will need to take these as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sure this would work but it looks more like using reflection rather than functional programming. I am a total newbie here so it may be the same thing?